# Cannot resolve bundle style

Tags: python, django, webpack

I'm trying to integrate Webpack into my Django Project.

This is my webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require('webpack');
const BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const VENDOR_LIBS = [
    'jquery', 'mustache'
];

const config = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry:  {
        app: 'app.js',
        vendor: VENDOR_LIBS,
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './static/bundles/'),
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['env']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: "css-loader"
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: { limit: 40000 }
                    },
                    'image-webpack-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            names: ['vendor', 'manifest']
        }),
        new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css')
    ],
    resolve: {
        modules: ['./static/assets/', './static/assets/javascript/', './static/assets/css/', 'node_modules']
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

I'm also using the django-webpack-loader, and I have the following settings on my settings.py file:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/bundles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
        'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'bundles/',
        'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'webpack-stats.json'),
        # 'CACHE': not DEBUG
    }
}
```

For some reason I'm getting a WebpackBundleLookupError at /
"Cannot resolve bundle style"

```
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
{% render_bundle 'manifest' %}
{% render_bundle 'vendor' %}
{% render_bundle 'app' 'js' %}
{% render_bundle 'style' 'css' %}
```

Loading the javascript works fine, but when I'm trying to also load my css bundled file, I get that error.

Regards,

Anthony

Comment: hey @Anthony did you ever get this working? I am having the same issue right now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the `render_bundle` pattern at work here, and it's been years since I worked with django, but it looks like the other three `render_bundle` statements are referencing chunks that your webpack config has defined. `manifest` and `vendor` would be output by the `CommonsChunkPlugin` and `app` is your entry chunk. Nothing in that config seems to be creating a chunk named `style`, however. Are you trying to capture the output of the `ExtractTextPlugin`? That plugin writes a `.css` file to disk rather than creating a webpack chunk, so you would normally reference that CSS file in your HTML.